# $E(\mathbb F_q) \simeq (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$. What is $q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $q$ be a prime power, so that $\mathbb F_q$ is the field on $q$ elements, and suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve with group structure $E(\mathbb F_q) \simeq (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$.

I want to show that either 
\begin{align*}
q&=n^2 + 1, \\
q&=n^2 \pm n  +1, \text{ or}\\
q&=n^2\pm 2n + 1 = (n^2\pm 1),
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I'm guessing I need to use some reasoning with torsion points of the curve, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed. I appreciate any help.